# Create if-statement for all variables laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, if-statement

I am using laravel 5.5. I am creating a table highlighting various records for different stages and years. Right now, each year and stage has its own variable. I want to hide records that come back 0-0. Right now I am doing it this way:

```
<td>{{$roundoneyearone}}-{{$roundoneyearoneloss}}</td>


  @if(($roundtwoyearone || $roundtwoyearoneloss) == 0)
```

```
@else
      <td>{{$roundtwoyearone}}-{{$roundtwoyearoneloss}}</td>

@endif
```

Is there a way to set a global if-statement for all variables stating that if any two variables equal 0 and 0 that they will all be hidden? Perhaps with CSS?  I am also stuck trying to figure out a loop for these if anybody wants to tackle that aspect of it, but I want to research a bit more on that before I ask that question individually.

Comment: If you do not want to show the matching rows I would tackle it at the Sql level. Filter them out before sending the results to the view.

Comment: Why don't you do this from the controller? I see your are working with the blade

Comment: How are you querying these records and how are you passing them from the Controller to the View?

Comment: Here is my controller:    $roundtwoyearonea= GameData::where('homeTeam', $teamdatas)->where('homeWin', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'two')->where('year', '2005')->count();
        $roundtwoyearoneb= GameData::where('awayteam', $teamdatas)->where('awayWin', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'two')->where('year', '2005')->count();
        $roundtwoyearone= $roundtwoyearonea + $roundtwoyearoneb;

Comment: It might be better if I could figure out how to loop through years without having to create a new variable for each year. I will ask that question separately.